# How do you set a min and max value for the inter-arrival times of a poisson distribution?

Tags: python, max, min, poisson

Sometimes I'll get an _inter_arrival_time that's too small. How do I set a min and max for the _inter_arrival_time so that the value returned isn't less than the min value specified and more than the max value specified?

```
import math
import random
import statistics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_lambda = 0.00923579
_num_arrivals = input('Number of arrivals: ')
_arrival_id = []
_inter_arrival_times = []
_arrival_times = []
_arrival_time = 0

x = np.arange(0,1800,10)

for i in range(int(_num_arrivals)):
    _arrival_id.append(i)
    #Get a random probability value from the uniform distribution's PDF
    n = random.random()

    #Generate the inter-arrival time from the exponential distribution's CDF using the Inverse-CDF technique
    _inter_arrival_time = -math.log(1.0 - n) / _lambda
    _inter_arrival_times.append(_inter_arrival_time)
    

    #Add the inter-arrival time to the running sum to get the next absolute arrival time
    _arrival_time = _arrival_time + _inter_arrival_time
    _arrival_times.append(_arrival_time)
```

Comment: `-math.log(1.0 - n) / _lambda` set the min and mix to this expression

Comment: If you change the distribution of inter-event times by shifting or truncating it, the results no longer describe a Poisson process.